# How to access two seperate public ip range on win10 and layer 2 switch

Tags: windows-10, networking, routing

I want to get access two separate networks on win 10
I have layer 2 switch and my computer (win10) and my two routers are connected to switch.

Problem : i have no access to router's config console!!
router 1 : 192.168.1.1    class c pubic ip
router 2 : 172.20.1.1   class B public ip

**how can i config ipv4 settings on win 10 to access both networks at same time?
or
how can i add ip to mac routes in win 10 ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your ethernet setup

[image]

2. Open <kbd>Properties</kbd>

[image]

3. Select Internet Protocol Version 4 and Click on <kbd>Properties</kbd>

[image]

4. Click on <kbd>Advanced</kbd>

[image]

5. Click on <kbd>Add</kbd> under IP Addresses and add a static ip address if desired
6. Click on <kbd>Add</kbd> under Gateway and add the two router (dhcp) addresses
7. You end up like this

[image]

8. You will want to change the metric if you want your browsers (as an example) to use one router over other.